# ImageMap in Messenger BOT?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating chatBOTs for different channels including facebook messenger. I would like to have ImageMaps in messenger BOT. That is, **single images with different hotspots and each linking to different urls**. I know it is possible in some other channels; but could not find any way to do the same in messenger. Could somebody kindly guide me on this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure Messenger platform doesn't provide the ImageMaps function so far. The alternative way is opening Webview with "compact" hight.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview#height
Then, you can show a image with map tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: That’s awesome way to achieve the functionality. Thank you, will try it out